# Return a list, I already have a rowmapper implementation

Tags: java, spring, generics, jdbctemplate

In my UserDao I want to return a list of users.

I already have a `UserRowMapper` that `implements RowMapper<User>`.

How can I do this?

I tried:

```
List rows = getJdbcTemplate().queryforList("select * from users");

for(Map row : rows) {

}
```

But wasn't sure how to use my UserRowMapper to populate a User object and insert it into my list of users List.

BTW, is this the best generic list I shoudl be using:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
```

?

Comment: Maybe Dozer (or BeanCopy) could help you convert to the specified object type ? Do check them.

Comment: An `ArrayList` should be Good Enough (tm) most of the time. (I.e. when not inserting elements at the beginning / middle of a very very very big list.)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use [`JdbcTemplate.query(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper, Object... args)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper,%20java.lang.Object...%29), and you can pass in a variable number of values for the `?` placeholders as the last argument(s):

```
public List<User> findById(int userId)
{
    return getJdbcTemplate().query(
            "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=?",
            new UserRowMapper(),
            userId
        );
}
```

Or something like:

```
public List<User> findByManyParams(int param1, int param2, String param3)
{
    return getJdbcTemplate().query(
            "SELECT * FROM users WHERE foo=? AND bar=? AND foobar=?",
            new UserRowMapper(),
            param1,
            param2,
            param3
        );
}
```

The `query()` method is actually overloaded many times over, so you can usually find at least one flavor that works for what you need in any given situation.

Comment: this is perfect and correct example,just wanted to highlight for people who start with JdbcTemplate that in the query the last parameter `foobar` is String, but when we make query string, we DO NOT NEED to use quotes. Eg. this is correct `AND foobar=?`, but using quotes is incorrect, eg. this `AND foobar='?'` will yield an error. (maybe this little comment will help someone avoid a subtle bug)

Comment: @DimitryK up vote for calling out the subtle nuance :)

Answer (score 13):

Use [`query()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper%29), not `queryForList()`:

```
List<User> users = getJdbcTemplate().query("select * from users", new UserRowMapper());
```

Comment: but what if I have placeholders in my sql, like `"Select * from users where id > ?"`  when I add parameters, it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Blankman There's about a zillion overloads for that method listed in the documentation. One of them surely accepts placeholder values.

Comment: Bingo! I was using queryForList and getting a bad sql statement. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

A bit late for this question, but with Lambda expression and RowMapper, below statement worked for me for similar problem.

```
List<User> users = jdbcTemplate.query("select * from users", (rs, rowNum) -> new User(rs.getString("userId"), rs.getString("userName")));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class UsuarioBean {

    int idUsuario;
    String userName;
    String clave; 
    String nombres;
    String paterno;
    String materno;
    String correo;
    String direccion;
    String telefono;
    String estado;
    Date fec_alta;

    //......
}

//la interface RowMapper del modulo Spring JDBC
public class UsuarioMapper implements RowMapper<UsuarioBean>{

    public UsuarioBean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        UsuarioBean usuario = new UsuarioBean();
        //se esta realizando el mapeo del bean con las columnas de BD manualmente
        usuario.setIdUsuario(rs.getInt("id_usuario"));
        usuario.setUserName(rs.getString("username"));
        usuario.setClave(rs.getString("clave"));
        usuario.setNombres(rs.getString("nombres"));
        usuario.setPaterno(rs.getString("paterno"));
        usuario.setMaterno(rs.getString("materno"));
        usuario.setCorreo(rs.getString("correo"));
        usuario.setDireccion(rs.getString("direccion"));
        usuario.setTelefono(rs.getString("telefono"));
        usuario.setEstado(rs.getString("estado"));
        usuario.setFec_alta(rs.getDate("fec_alta"));
        return usuario;
    }
}

public interface UsuarioDao{
    List<UsuarioBean> listarUsuarios();

    UsuarioBean obtenerUsuario(int idUsuario);

    int crearUsuario(UsuarioBean usuario);

    int modificarUsuario(UsuarioBean usuario);

    int eliminarUsuario(int idUsuario);
}

@Repository//con esto lo subimos al Spring Container
public class UsuarioDaoImpl implements UsuarioDao{

    @Autowired//con esto estamos inyectando UsuarioDaoImpl el jdbcTemplate
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<UsuarioBean> listarUsuarios(){
        String sql="SELECT * FROM USUARIO";
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new UsuarioMapper());
    }

    @Override
    public UsuarioBean obtenerUsuario(int idUsuario){
        String sql="SELECT * FROM USUARIO WHERE ID_USUARIO=?";
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{idUsuario},new UsuarioMapper());
    }

    @Override
    public int crearUsuario(UsuarioBean usuario){
        String sql="INSERT INTO USUARIO(username,clave,nombres,paterno,materno,correo,direccion,telefono,fec_alta,estado) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        Object[] params=new Object[]{usuario.getUserName(),usuario.getClave(),usuario.getNombres(),usuario.getPaterno(),usuario.getMaterno(),usuario.getCorreo(),usuario.getDireccion(),usuario.getTelefono(),this.convertirFecha(usuario.getFec_alta()),usuario.getEstado()};
        return jdbcTemplate.update(sql,params);
    }

    @Override
    public int modificarUsuario(UsuarioBean usuario){
        String sql="UPDATE USUARIO SET username=?,clave=?,nombres=?,paterno=?,materno=?,correo=?,direccion=?,telefono=?,estado=? WHERE ID_USUARIO=?";
        Object[] params=new Object[]{usuario.getUserName(),usuario.getClave(),usuario.getNombres(),usuario.getPaterno(),usuario.getMaterno(),usuario.getCorreo(),usuario.getDireccion(),usuario.getTelefono(),usuario.getEstado(),usuario.getIdUsuario()};
        return jdbcTemplate.update(sql,params);
    }

    @Override
    public int eliminarUsuario(int idUsuario){
        String sql="DELETE FROM USUARIO WHERE ID_USUARIO=?";

        return jdbcTemplate.update(sql,new Object[]{idUsuario});
    }

    public java.sql.Date convertirFecha(java.util.Date fecha){
        return new Date((Objects.nonNull(fecha))?fecha.getTime():null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain you answer (and in *English). Code-only answers aren't that helpful.