# Spring MVC i.e Get Model object in which only ArrayList attribute must be initialized and remaining attributes should not be initialized

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

======NewContact.jsp==============0

Here I'm getting the Model object and rendering happly.

======Users.java(Model Class)======1

```
package com.one.model;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Users
{

  private ArrayList<String> al;
  private String x;
  private int y;

  // getters and setters

   }
```

===============UsersDao.java(Dao interface)========2

```
package com.one.dao;
import com.one.model.Users;
public interface UsersDao {
   public Users getModified(Users glist);
   }
}
```

==============UsersDaoImpl.java(Dao Implementation)=======3

```
package com.one.daoimpl;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor;
import com.one.dao.UsersDao;
import com.one.model.Users;

public class UsersDaoImpl implements UsersDao {

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
public UsersDaoImpl(DataSource dataSource) 
{
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}


@Override
public Users getModified(Users glist)
{
    String sql1 = "SELECT user_group FROM users";
   //Here I was strucked.
    return glist;
}

}
```

Here I was strucked. I have JdbcTemplate class obj. This is Spring MVC application. I'm able to executing other queries here,no problem. And displaying the all the values in the view pages no problem. But I need get drop down menu in NewContact.jsp. For that I'm creating Model object in Controller class and Sending that model object to  the NewContact.jsp i.e view page. but how can I inject only user_group values from the databse table,assume "users"(is table) and "name,sal,user_group"(are the columns OF "users" table).

Finally, when I am returning an object(i.e object of the Model'Users.java') from the UsersDaoImpl class,only model object "ArrayList al" must be initialized. But x and y variables should not be initialized. I Don't want to use AJAX here.

Comment: I've edited your question to format code as code, because you're new here. Next time, format it correctly, and don't post it until it looks correct.

Comment: Oh! sorry. I'm very newer to this environment. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do here is first to create a DAO implementation that returns a list of objects that you want to display in the drop down menu.Then use Spring annotation @ResponseBody in one of your controller method, and return a `json` array that contains the values that you want to included in your dropdown.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Object> getObject() {
        //from here call the DAO implementation for returning the object, even tho you suppose to include a service layer.
    }
```

Now, you gonna need use some jQuery in your JSP:

A simple drop down can be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function() {
                $.getJSON('<spring:url value="your JSON file URL path here"/>', {
                    ajax : 'true'
                }, function(data){
                    var html = '<option value="">--Please select one--</option>';
                    var len = data.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        html += '<option value="' + data[i].desc + '">'
                                + data[i].desc + '</option>';
                    }
                    html += '</option>';

                    $('#dropDownSelect').html(html);
                });

            });

    </script>
```

And JSP:

```
<select id="dropDownSelect"/>
```

Comment: Is it possible without using JQuery,Ajax

Comment: Sir, Actually I don't know anything about JQuery,Ajax..etc.

Comment: You can have a look at this if u don't want to use jquery, should get you started pretty good: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/

Comment: Insted of sending only new object to NewContact.jsp ,I need to send Model Object , in which only ArrayList<String> attribute is initializes with values

Comment: No, you can create a list that only contains `UserGroups`, for example, `List<UserGroups> list;` And you just need to create a DAO implementation, such as this: `public List<UserGroups> getUserGroups(){   ...here you use JDBC to return the data...}`

Comment: public List<Groups> list()          {
     String sql = "SELECT * FROM groups";
  List<Groups> listContact = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new     RowMapper<Groups>() {

    @Override
   public Groups mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    
    Groups glist = new Groups();
 
    glist.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
     glist.setName(rs.getString("name"));
    glist.setIs_active(rs.getInt("is_active"));
    glist.setTenant_id(rs.getLong("tenant_id"));
    
    
    return glist;
   }
   
  });
  
  return listContact;
 }

Comment: public Users getModified(Users glist)
{
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT user_group FROM users";
   //++++
    return glist;
}
//++++ here which method of jdbcTemplate class I have to use to pass "sqlQuery" and retrive the  'user_group' column of 'users' table and assign those 'user_group' values to attribute ArrayList<String> of Users Model object. Here I no need to assign any values to  'x and y' of Users Model object. If once this over, then I will get the Users Model Object in New Contacts.jsp with  'x and y' I get the values from user. and "ArrayList<String>" contains the values from DB.

Comment: r u using jdbc template? if you are, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966821/return-a-list-i-already-have-a-rowmapper-implementation

Comment: I think that code is to return the list of objects. my requirement is to return only one object . In that one object only one attribute value initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best choice is create a form-class to initialize the values after get it. In controller, before adding the form into the model, set the list and give the others at null.

Comment: Can you please provide related url's. Then I can easily get relevant information. I mean i din't use form-class so far.